# jq select with multiple conditions

Tags: jq

I have the following few json objects that Id like to filter using a single `jq` command.

```
[
  {
    "version": "v2",
    "transactionId": "10590541.2280012772",
    "description": {
      "original": "DUMMY",
      "sanitized": "DUMMY A.B. C"
    }
  }
]
```

or

```
[
  {
    "version": "v2",
    "transactionId": "10590541.2280012772",
    "description": {
      "original": "DUMMY",
      "sanitized": "DUMMY A.B. C"
    },
    "merchantDetails": {
      "name": "DUMMY"
    }
  }
]
```

or

```
[
  {
    "version": "v2",
    "transactionId": "10590541.2280012772",
    "merchantDetails": {
      "name": "DUMMY"
    }
  }
]
```

Im trying to filter with `jq` so either of the above json objects satisfy the filter condition.
In other words, if both `.merchantDetails.name` and `.description.sanitized` exist then `.merchantDetails.name` has to take precedence when checking for the string "DUMMY". If not then check either `.merchantDetails.name` or `.description.sanitized` for the string "DUMMY".

What i currently have is the following which doesn't really work.

```
jq . test.json  | jq '.[] | select( (.merchantDetails.name | try contains ("DUMMY")) or (.description.sanitized | try contains ("DUMMY")) )'
```

Anyway to achieve this using a single in-line `jq` command ?

Comment: You say "either" should satisfy the condition, but there are 3 JSON examples.

Comment: I mean either of the json objects should satisfy the filter condition. 
"If both .merchantDetails.name and .description.sanitized exist then .merchantDetails.name has to take precedence when checking for the string "DUMMY". If not either one will do to filter"

Comment: Added more explanation around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a multi level conditional evaluation, because having to check different fields on different conditions

```
jq '
map (
  objects |
  if   has("merchantDetails") and has("description") then
    select( .merchantDetails.name  | contains("DUMMY"))
  elif has("merchantDetails") then
    select( .merchantDetails.name  | contains("DUMMY"))
  elif has("description") then
    select( .description.sanitized | contains("DUMMY"))
  else empty
  end
)
'
```